Optimize code to find nearest subsets of points to a list of values
I have two one-dimensional arrays A and B (say of length m and n, respectively), and some number n_0 with 0 < n_0 < n. I am looking for the most efficient way to identify the n_0 nearest points in B to each individual element of A.
That is, I need to produce an m x n boolean array M such that:

The ith column of M contains exactly n_0 1's, and n-n_0 0's
The locations in M[:,i] with a 1 are the indices of the n_0 points of B which are the nearest to the point A[i].

Here is what I have tried.
import numpy as np

m = 1000
n = 1200
n_0 = 300

A = np.random.rand(m)
B = np.random.rand(n)

A_dist, B_dist = np.meshgrid(A, B, sparse=True, copy=False)

dist = (A_dist - B_dist)**2

qq = np.quantile(dist, n_0/n, axis = 0)

M = (dist <= qq)

The reason I think that this could be improved on is that the computation of the quantiles in the second to last line is not taking advantage of the source of the matrix dist - namely that the ith and jth columns of dist are distances from two points A[i,0] and A[j,0] to the exact same values, in B.
Any ideas are welcome!

See Nearest neighbour search. I would personally use a k-d tree like data structure for this. The resulting complexity should be significantly better than the one of your (naive) code (which is certainly O(n**2) if not even O(n**3) regarding the exact underlying algorithm used by Numpy for np.quantile -- like QuickSelect -- and actual input data).

Do you have any guarantees on the size of n_0 relative to n?

My idea is that if you sort both A and B, the search part will be O(N).
To better understand the logic, let's look at the result when A and B are already sorted.
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.sort(np.random.rand(20))  # A is sorted!
B = np.sort(np.random.rand(10))  # B is sorted!
n_0 = 3

M = # Calculate M 
for i, row in enumerate(M.T):
    print(f"A[{i}]:", row)

A[0]: [ True  True  True False False False False False False False]
A[1]: [ True  True  True False False False False False False False]
A[2]: [ True  True  True False False False False False False False]
A[3]: [False False  True  True  True False False False False False]
A[4]: [False False  True  True  True False False False False False]
A[5]: [False False  True  True  True False False False False False]
A[6]: [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
A[7]: [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
A[8]: [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
A[9]: [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
A[10]: [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
A[11]: [False False False False  True  True  True False False False]
A[12]: [False False False False False  True  True  True False False]
A[13]: [False False False False False  True  True  True False False]
A[14]: [False False False False False  True  True  True False False]
A[15]: [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
A[16]: [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
A[17]: [False False False False False False False  True  True  True]
A[18]: [False False False False False False False  True  True  True]
A[19]: [False False False False False False False  True  True  True]

Since I have transposed the M, each row represents the n_0 nearest neighbor mask for each element of the A.
You will notice that the three consecutive Trues slide from left to right.
This means that the search part only has to determine how much to slide the window for each element of A.
So, if we process the elements of A one by one iteratively, the total count of slides is at most len(B), which makes the search part O(len(A) + len(B)).
For any (unsorted) A and B, the same search can be done using argsort.
In pure Python, such an iterative and high overhead process is not efficient, but using Numba makes it possible.
Here is the implementation and benchmark.
(My solution is find_nearest_subsets. I'll explain later what find_nearest_subsets_transposed is.)
import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange


def original(A, B, n_0):  # Your original solution.
    A_dist, B_dist = np.meshgrid(A, B, sparse=True, copy=False)
    dist = (A_dist - B_dist) ** 2
    qq = np.quantile(dist, n_0 / len(B), axis=0)
    M = dist <= qq
    return M


@njit(cache=True)
def find_nearest_window(sorted_arr, value, n):  # A helper function for find_nearest_subsets.
    """Find a window that contains the n nearest elements to the value from the sorted array.

    Returns left and right, where sorted_arr[left:right] is the window.
    """
    assert 0 < n < len(sorted_arr)

    left = right = np.searchsorted(sorted_arr, value)
    # At this point, the window contains 0 elements.
    # Expand the window until it contains n elements.
    for _ in range(n):
        if left == 0:
            right += 1
        elif right == len(sorted_arr):
            left -= 1
        elif (sorted_arr[right] - value) < (value - sorted_arr[left - 1]):  # One right element vs. one left element.
            right += 1
        else:
            left -= 1
    return left, right


@njit(cache=True)
def find_nearest_subsets(a, b, n):
    # Sort both arrays.
    a_sorted_arg = np.argsort(a)
    a_sorted = a[a_sorted_arg]
    b_sorted_arg = np.argsort(b)
    b_sorted = b[b_sorted_arg]

    # Result matrix.
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(len(b_sorted), len(a_sorted)), dtype=np.bool_)

    # Find the window on b_sorted that contains the n nearest elements to the first element of a_sorted.
    left, right = find_nearest_window(b_sorted, a_sorted[0], n)
    matrix[b_sorted_arg[left: right], a_sorted_arg[0]] = True

    # Find the window for the remaining elements of a, by sliding the window to the right.
    # Note that we don't need to slide the window to the left, because both arrays are sorted.
    for i in range(1, len(a_sorted)):
        ai = a_sorted[i]

        # Repeatedly slide the window until the difference becomes greater.
        while right < len(b_sorted) and (b_sorted[right] - ai) < (ai - b_sorted[left]):
            right += 1
            left += 1

        matrix[b_sorted_arg[left: right], a_sorted_arg[i]] = True

    return matrix


@njit(cache=True)
def find_nearest_subsets_transposed(a, b, n):
    # Sort both arrays.
    a_sorted_arg = np.argsort(a)
    a_sorted = a[a_sorted_arg]
    b_sorted_arg = np.argsort(b)
    b_sorted = b[b_sorted_arg]

    # Result matrix.
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(len(a_sorted), len(b_sorted)), dtype=np.bool_)

    # Find the window on b_sorted that contains the n nearest elements to the first element of a_sorted.
    left, right = find_nearest_window(b_sorted, a_sorted[0], n)
    matrix[a_sorted_arg[0], b_sorted_arg[left: right]] = True

    # Find the window for the remaining elements of a, by sliding the window to the right.
    # Note that we don't need to slide the window to the left, because both arrays are sorted.
    for i in range(1, len(a_sorted)):
        ai = a_sorted[i]

        # Repeatedly slide the window until the difference becomes greater.
        while right < len(b_sorted) and (b_sorted[right] - ai) < (ai - b_sorted[left]):
            right += 1
            left += 1

        matrix[a_sorted_arg[i], b_sorted_arg[left: right]] = True

    return matrix.T


@njit(parallel=True)
def compute_M_numba(A, B, n_0):  # Andrej Kesely's solution
    m = len(A)
    n = len(B)
    B_sorted_idx = np.argsort(B)
    B_sorted = B[B_sorted_idx]

    M = np.zeros(shape=(n, m), dtype="uint8")

    indices = np.searchsorted(B_sorted, A)
    for i in prange(len(indices)):
        idx = indices[i]

        l, h = idx - n_0, idx + n_0

        if l < 0:
            l = 0

        if h >= len(B):
            h = len(B)

        tmp = np.argsort(np.abs(B_sorted[l:h] - A[i]))
        closest = B_sorted_idx[l + tmp[:n_0]]
        M[closest, i] = 1

    return M


def benchmark():
    np.random.seed(0)
    a = np.random.rand(1000)
    b = np.random.rand(1200)
    n_0 = 300

    expected = original(a, b, n_0)

    candidates = [
        original,
        compute_M_numba,
        find_nearest_subsets,
        find_nearest_subsets_transposed,
    ]
    name_len = max(len(f.__name__) for f in candidates)

    for f in candidates:
        assert np.array_equal(f(a, b, n_0), expected), f"{f.__name__} failed"
        t = timeit.repeat(lambda: f(a, b, n_0), repeat=5, number=1)
        print(f"{f.__name__:{name_len}} : {min(t)}")


benchmark()

Result:
original                        : 0.022209368995390832
compute_M_numba                 : 0.0035642310976982117
find_nearest_subsets            : 0.0007081379881128669
find_nearest_subsets_transposed : 0.00039287691470235586

Regarding the computational complexity, assuming that N = max(n, m) and n_0 is proportional to N,
the sorting is O(N log N), the first window search is O(N), then subsequent searches are O(N),
and the creation of M and the assignment of values to M is O(N^2).
Therefore, in total, it is still O(N^2).
Since sorting is likely to be implemented very efficiently, it can be said that most of the runtime is spent assigning values to M.
The performance of find_nearest_subsets_transposed supports this hypothesis.
The find_nearest_subsets_transposed is, as the name suggests, a version that uses M transposed to n x m instead of m x n.
By transposing the M, performance was greatly improved by improving memory contiguity.
In other words, unless you change the way the results are stored, I don't think you'll get any significantly better performance than this.

You can try to leverage numba parallelism to compute M:
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def compute_M_orig(A, B, m, n, n_0):
    A_dist, B_dist = np.meshgrid(A, B, sparse=True, copy=False)
    dist = (A_dist - B_dist) ** 2
    qq = np.quantile(dist, n_0 / n, axis=0)
    M = dist <= qq
    return M

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def compute_M_numba(A, B, m, n, n_0):
    B_sorted_idx = np.argsort(B)
    B_sorted = B[B_sorted_idx]

    M = np.zeros(shape=(n, m), dtype="uint8")

    indices = np.searchsorted(B_sorted, A)
    for i in nb.prange(len(indices)):
        idx = indices[i]

        l, h = idx - n_0, idx + n_0

        if l < 0:
            l = 0

        if h >= len(B):
            h = len(B)

        tmp = np.argsort(np.abs(B_sorted[l:h] - A[i]))
        closest = B_sorted_idx[l + tmp[:n_0]]
        M[closest, i] = 1

    return M


m = 10
n = 15
n_0 = 6

np.random.seed(0)

A = np.random.rand(m)
B = np.random.rand(n)

m1 = compute_M_orig(A, B, m, n, n_0)
m2 = compute_M_numba(A, B, m, n, n_0)

assert np.allclose(m1, m2)


Benchmark with perfplot:
import perfplot


def _setup(m):
    A = np.random.rand(m)
    B = np.random.rand(m + int(m * 0.5))
    return A, B, len(A), len(B), int(len(B) * 0.3)


perfplot.show(
    setup=_setup,
    kernels=[
        compute_M_orig,
        compute_M_numba,
    ],
    labels=["orig", "numba"],
    n_range=[500, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 25_000],
    xlabel="m",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=np.allclose,
)

Creates on my AMD 5700x this graph:

